# Linear regression with three parameters

Tags: statistics, linear-regression

I need to fit linear lines with three parameters to a set of data.  An example set of data is [displayed here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aV5SJ.png). (The actual values of the data don't matter so much as the algorithm to solve the problem since I need to apply this method to multiple data sets)

The form of the fit must be:

- For the circles: $y = ax + b$
- For the squares: $y = ax + b + c$
- For the triangles: $y = ax + b - c$

What is the best way to preform this linear regression with the added $c$ constraint?

Comment: Add categorical variable with 3 possible values (circle, square, triangle) to your model, [course available here](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat501/node/301).

Comment: @iiivooo Thanks, I've never heard of "multiple linear regressions" before.  I was looking for a mathematical definition I could implement in my own code rather than a software package as used in the course link you provided, but I found what I was looking for [here](http://dept.stat.lsa.umich.edu/~kshedden/Courses/Stat401/Notes/401-multreg.pdf).  Thanks for getting me started!

Answer (score 1):

As  iiivooo commented, you need to add a  categorical variable to describe the full data set.

The problem statement almost tells you what to do : the data points being $(x_i,y_i)$, for each data point add a parameter $z$ such that $z_i=0$ if the data point corresponds to a circle, $z_i=+1$ if the data point corresponds to a square,  $z_i=-1$ if the data point corresponds to a triangle.

So, the data points are now $(x_i,y_i,z_i)$ and you need to perform the multilinear regression $$y=a +bx+cz$$ If you use matric calculations, the problem is simple. If you prefer the so-clled normal equations, they will then be $$\sum_{i=1}^n y_i=na+b\sum_{i=1}^n x_i+c\sum_{i=1}^n z_i$$ $$\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i=a\sum_{i=1}^n x_i+b\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2+c\sum_{i=1}^n x_iz_i$$ $$\sum_{i=1}^n z_iy_i=a\sum_{i=1}^n z_i+b\sum_{i=1}^n x_i z_i+c\sum_{i=1}^n z_i^2$$ you have to solve for $a,b,c$.

Changing notations, you would then have as solutions :

$$c=\frac{-n \,\text{Sxx}\, \text{Szy}+n \,\text{Sxy}\, \text{Sxz}+\text{Sx}^2\,
   \text{Szy}-\text{Sx}\,\text{Sxy}\, \text{Sz}-\text{Sx}\, \text{Sxz}\,
   \text{Sy}+\text{Sxx}\, \text{Sy}\, \text{Sz}}{-n \,\text{Sxx} \,\text{Szz}+n
  \, \text{Sxz}^2+\text{Sx}^2\, \text{Szz}-2 \text{Sx}\, \text{Sxz} \,\text{Sz}+\text{Sxx}\,
   \text{Sz}^2}$$ $$b=\frac{c \,n \,\text{Sxz}-c \,\text{Sx} \,\text{Sz}-n\, \text{Sxy}+\text{Sx}\,
   \text{Sy}}{\text{Sx}^2-n\, \text{Sxx}}$$ $$a=\frac{-b\, \text{Sx}-c\, \text{Sz}+\text{Sy}}{n}$$